# Mounting a directory from the host in boot2docker for Windows

Tags: windows, bash, windows-8.1, cygwin, docker

I'm running docker 1.6 and `boot2docker` on a Windows 8.1 box. When I use the Boot2Docker Start shortcut, it takes me to a cygwin bash prompt where I can run docker commands natively.

I'm having trouble mounting a directory from my users folder. I've tried:

```
$ docker run -d --name abe -v $APPDATA/Bitcoin:/datadir poliver/bitcoin-abe
```

I get the error:

```
invalid value "C:\\Users\\someone\\AppData\\Roaming/Bitcoin:/datadir"
for flag -v: \Users\someone\AppData\Roaming/Bitcoin:/datadir 
is not an absolute path 
See 'c:\Program Files\Boot2DockeForWindows\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I get the same results when I call it these ways:

```
$ docker run -d --name abe -v "$APPDATA/Bitcoin":/datadir poliver/bitcoin-abe
$ docker run -d --name abe -v "/c/users/someone/AppData/Roaming/Bitcoin":/datadir poliver/bitcoin-abe
$ docker run -d --name abe -v ~/AppData/Roaming/Bitcoin:/datadir poliver/bitcoin-abe
```

I've also tried:

```
$ docker run -d --name abe -v ~/APPDATA/Bitcoin:/datadir poliver/bitcoin-abe
```

And I've gotten the error:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: cannot bind mount volume: ~\AppData\Bitcoin volume paths must be absolute.
```

It seems like cygwin bash is replacing `/` with `\` and then docker parses the argument passed to `-v` and can't accept it.

Comment: On my boot2docker installation, the command "ls /c/Users" lists my Windows 8.1 C:\Users folder. Do you need to mount other locations?

Comment: I can certainly see `/c/Users` from the boot2docker linux VM (the host). But I need the poliver/bitcoin-abe container to mount a specific folder from `/c/Users` at the `/datadir` mount point on the container.

Comment: I also seem to experience the same problem unable to mount a host folder. `$ docker run -d -v /c/Users/310145787/Desktop/mongo:/data/db mongo
invalid value "c:\\Users\\310145787\\Desktop\\mongo;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\data\\db" for flag -v: \Users\310145787\Desktop\mongo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\data\db is not an absolute path`

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem?

Comment: Sorry Marco, no solution yet. :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to mount the `$APPDATA` on your Windows host machine to `/datadir` on the docker container, instead of the below command:

```
docker run -d --name abe -v $APPDATA/Bitcoin:/datadir poliver/bitcoin-abe
```

You can issue:

```
docker run -d --name abe -v //c/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/$APPDATA/Bitcoin:/datadir poliver/bitcoin-abe
```

`//c/Users/PATH_TO_DIR` **is the key here for Windows directory**

Your `$APPDATA` Directory **MUST** reside on the `/c/Users/Your_User_Name` directory and it **cannot** reside on other places. (e.g. `D:/$APPDATA` on the D partition.)

Answer (score 6):

see: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12590

> If you're using git bash on windows, msysgit converts paths like /c/users to c:\users (not something you want because the path inside the boot2docker VM is /c/Users)
>
> On cmd.exe/powershell you shouldn't be having this problem.